# Optimization problem with 5 categorical features and 5 numerical features and only 1 numerical output

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, genetic-algorithm, bayesian, categorical-data

I want to find the structural parameters of a layered composite that produces my desired output.
Consider that I have a layered structure. The number of layers is 5. Each layer has a thickness within the values that are defined, t1 to t5. The material of each layer is chosen from 10 available materials.

If we label the materials with M1 to M10, one input sample can be presented as below:

[image: Schematic of the problem]

10 INPUT FEATURES: [ 150.2, 120, 70, 34.5, 256, M1, M5, M5, M8, M10]
1 OUTPUT: [2500]

So, the total parameters will be 10; 5 numerical parameters, the thicknesses, and 5 categorical parameters, the materials used in the layers. The output is the power out of this composite and is a numerical value. I want to find the structural parameters that produce the highest output value for me.
I was wondering if you could please help me and let me know how I can solve my optimization problem. Please let me know what the best way is to do my optimization. I am currently studying Bayesian and Genetic algorithms to solve my problem.

I tried to model my optimization problem in Keras using MLP (multilayer perceptron), however, I did not get good answer. Thank you so much in advance for your help.